# Best method of creating two classes that have the same variables, but with different access methods

Tags: c#, class, oop, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I know that by extending a class you can create a child class that has access to all of the variables and methods of its parent. However what I'm trying to achieve is one class with a number of required variables that are all editable from the editor window; and another that has all of those same variables, but with some that are not not editable and, instead have default values.

My specific example is a dialogue class that has a number of public variables:

```
public class Dialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Public variables for determining whether the dialogue has automatic or manual triggering; and whether it's single use
    public bool isAutomatic, isSingleUse;

    // Public variables for determining whether an unlocked discovery is required in order to trigger the dialogue at all
    public bool requiresDiscovery;
    public string requiresDiscoveryType;
    public int requiresDiscoveryId;

    // Public lists for general conversations and default topic sentences
    public List<Conversation> generalConversations;
    public List<Sentence> defaultTopicSentences;

    // Public variable for holding the optional topics in our conversation (can be left empty if desired)
    public List<Topic> topics;

    /* Methods here... */

}
```

The above class is used in both Dialogue events and also Cutscene events (which can contain multiple dialogues with character movements and other more complicated stuff). It is perfect for the dialogue events, but I could do with creating a variant class where some of the variables (e.g. isAutomatic, isSingleUse, requiresDiscovery etc..) are set automatically to false with no option to alter them in the editor. This is because some of the variables are not relevant to Cutscene events and could potentially cause issues if set to true.

What I'm getting stuck with is whether I can use Dialogue as a parent and somehow override the public access of certain variables in the child class; or if there's another way this has to be done. If someone could give me a code example of how I can achieve the above that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems almost like an X/Y problem type question. You seem to be violating the Single Responsibility Principle. If you have a class dealing with Dialogue and one with Cutscenes this wouldn't be an issue in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, you might be on to something there... are you by any chance suggesting a generic dialogue parent class and then a child class for single Dialogue Events and separate child class for Cutscenes?

Comment: In what way is a Cutscene a type of Dialogue? You even state `can contain multiple dialogues with character movements and other more`

Comment: Sorry, I may not be describing the situation correctly. I have a DialogueController which can be passed a single instance of the Dialogue class described above. My cutscenes are controlled from a CutsceneController class which can be passed many Dialogue instances and runs through them in order. The CutsceneController itself calls the DialogueController each time it runs a Dialogue instance (as well as doing a bunch of other things). So what I meant was having a child class of Dialogue for passing directly to the DialogueController and a separate child for passing to the CutsceneController.

Comment: What you describe sounds fine, what exactly is the question? If have common properties that apply to both then make that an abstract parent of each, but it in itself is not a dialogue or cutscene event. Only the public properties that apply in each case belong to each child class.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with inheritance, otherwise you will either end up with code duplication with the same properties in two classes, or trying to botch together a single class for two uses, which goes against SRP. Having them separate will make your life a lot easier.

By doing that, you will be able to have multiple Dialogue classes in a Cutscene, but still have the features of a Dialogue in a Cutscene itself.

Create a new class called `Cutscene` and set whatever `Dialogue` variables you need when creating a new instance of `Cutscene`.

```cs
public class Cutscene : Dialogue
{
     // Set whatever you need to false to prevent any issues
     public Cutscene() {
          this.isAutomatic = false;
          this.isSingleUse = false;
          this.requiresDiscovery = false
          // etc...
     }
}
```

If you want to learn more about inheritance, [MSDN has a great page on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance)